# NSE data not fetching for a particular date

Tags: google-sheets

I am using GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:MSTCLTD", "close", today()-(360 * 1.5), today()) in google sheet. Hence data for 15/01/2024 is populated. But when using GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:3MINDIA", "close", today()-(360 * 1.5), today()), data for 15/01/2024 is not populated.

The output could be observed with link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14mmaO7aUYQWjqm_K3z7cqwYqy9Q_GxWMTtLdtI0x-Qc/edit?usp=sharing

I have checked with NSE website and found that data exists. It may be checked with link 3[M India Limited Share Price Today, Stock Price, Live NSE News, Quotes, Tips – NSE India](https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=3MINDIA)

Need help to resolve the issue of date.

Regards,

Swarup

Answer (score 0):

If you enter "NSE:3MINDIA" in Google Search and hover over its graph, no data is available for January 15th either.

So, this issue does not seem related to Google Sheets but rather to the data Google has about the National Stock Exchange of India.

By the way, the Google Sheets document you provided a link to cannot be opened because it was not shared.

Comment: Sorry. Hope you will get the sheet with below link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14mmaO7aUYQWjqm_K3z7cqwYqy9Q_GxWMTtLdtI0x-Qc/edit?usp=sharing. Further could you please refer below link for data of 3MINDIA? https://www.google.com/finance/quote/3MINDIA:NSE?window=5D

Comment: The link does indeed work now. It's odd that when selecting the "1 month" view, no data for January 15th seems to be available, but when choosing the "5 days" view, it does seem to be available.